# How do I plot a vector?

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector, matplotlib-3d

I was trying to plot the following vector `(B = [x, py, -(p+1)z])` from a paper that I'm working on.
I have taken `$p$ equal to 1` in order to replicate a graph from the paper.

I wrote the following code to plot the vector,(Best I could do to replicate the original)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import linspace, meshgrid

A = linspace(-4,4,10)

x,y = meshgrid(A,A)

p = 1

Bx = x
By = p*y

plt.quiver(x,y,Bx,By)
plt.show()`
```

The output of the graph is below.
[image: My output]

But the intended graphs are as follows
[image: Graphs from the paper]

I'm trying to plot both of them but the code I wrote only plots the 2D plot.

Comment: You only got a 2D quiver plot because you only asked for a 2D plot.